# Calling user-defined database functions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Is this possible? I mean, I'm basically looking to do the following...

I have created a function already in my database (although if there's a way to create it using code first migrations, that's fine by me too) called GetPlayerPosition that accepts 1 parameter (an integer representing a Player ID).

I'm looking to do something like this with LINQ in my MVC code:

```
from p in db.Players
select new { p.PlayerId, GetPlayerPosition(p.PlayerId)};
```

I know I can't just simply do this, unfortunately (at least not without someway of getting EF to recognize this function), but I've tried hunting around for a while to find a way to do this and I'm just spinning my wheels. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Code First Functions convention](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/08/11/the-beta-version-of-store-functions-for-entityframework-6-1-1-code-first-available/) to invoke stored procedures, TVFs and scalar UDFs from Code First (EF 6.1.1).

Comment: I will take a look at this, thanks a lot for the info, Pawel! I unfortunately can't vote up though due to being a new user.